# Create shortcut in Quick Launch Folder

Tags: wix, wix3.9

Is there any built-in function in WiX that allows me to create a shortcut in
the Quick launch folder just like I'm able to create a desktop shortcut?

I use Wix v3.9 R2.

Thanks in advance

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

The Quick Launch is a simple folder in your AppData profile. To create a shortcut there, use the following:

```
<Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="MicrosoftFolder" Name="Microsoft">
        <Directory Id="InternetExplorerFolder" Name="Internet Explorer">
            <Directory Id="QuickLaunchFolder" Name="Quick Launch" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<File Id="MyApp" Name="My Test App.exe">
    <Shortcut Id="Shortcut"
            Name="My App"
            Description="My App"
            Directory="QuickLaunchFolder"
            WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
</File>
```